# Count rows across columns in a dataframe if they are greater than another value

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'BU': ['Total', 'Total', 'Total', 'CRS', 'CRS', 'CRS'], 
    'Line_Item': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses'],
    '1Q16': [100, 120, 0, 200, 190, 210],
    '2Q16': [100, 0, 130, 200, 190, 210],
    '3Q16': [200, 250, 0, 120, 0, 190]})
```

I want an output that counts the number of rows in 1Q16, 2Q16, 3Q16 columns that are greater than 0. So the output could be a list with entries `[5, 5, 4]`

I tried `.loc` for slicing, but since zeros appear on different rows on different columns I can't do that. I want to loop through particular columns and count entries that are greater than 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using boolean masking here.

```
cols = ['1Q16','2Q16','3Q16']
df[cols].gt(0).sum()
```

Output will be as follows:

```
1Q16    5
2Q16    5
3Q16    4
dtype: int64
```

***Simple explanation would be:***

- Creating list named `cols` which has column values in it(where we want to work upon).
- Using `gt(0)` to get all elements which are greater than `0` in df's columns(given in cols list).
- Then using `sum` function to sum all values more than 0 in given columns.

Comment: Thanks. Could I combine this output with a groupby of column "BU"? So the output is by group?

Comment: @postcolonialist, Your welcome. IMHO, since this is a new question apart from base question(changing question may confuse future users/readers), I would like to request you to open a new question and we could discuss it there.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = df.filter(regex=r"\dQ\d+").gt(0).sum().tolist()
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[5, 5, 4]
```

---

Or:

```
lst = (df.loc[:, "1Q16":] > 0).sum().tolist()
```